# How do pull shared variables with in the same group?

Tags: crystal-reports

My group 2 will always return 2 entries within Group 1. I'm running a subreport to pull a number I need to do calculations in the main report. This is the shared variable formula that I used in the subreport.

```
WhilePrintingRecords; 

Shared NumberVar sharedUsedUnits := {#TotalUnits};

sharedUsedUnits
```

It gives me the correct figure but when I pull it using this formula in the main report.

```
WhilePrintingRecords; 

NumberVar usedUnits;

Shared NumberVar sharedUsedUnits; 

usedUnits :=  sharedUsedUnits;
```

But for some reason it's pulling from the previous group.

So where I should see

```
Group 1
Group 2    244       244
Group 2    720       720
```

I'm instead seeing

```
Group 1
Group 2   244       0
Group 2   720       244
```

How do I get the correct shared variable to appear in the correct group? 
Thanks!

Comment: When you say previous group, do you mean a different group section, or a previous iteration of the same group section both formula appear within?

Comment: Previous iteration of the same group

Comment: The way your are using your formula should give the expected output.  I did a quick test to confirm and I got the expected output where the second number was always equal to the first.  Can you describe the subreport a bit?  In which section of the subreport is the formula to set the value of the variable?

Comment: It's in the Group 2 footer. I should have mentioned as well that these fields are in the Group 2 footer in the main report as well.

Comment: I just tried putting the field into the details section of the main report but the same problem is still happening.

Comment: So I tried putting the subreport in the group 2 header while keeping shared variable in the group 2 footer and that appears to work.

Comment: I found an error with my solution. If there is 0 in group 2 it pulls the figure from the other entry.

Comment: Is it the value 0 or a null value for the field in group 2?  I've seen cases where null values are thought to be 0 values.  In these cases I've used a formula field that checks for null and sets the value as 0 when the field I want to evaluate is null.  Then I would use that formula field in places of the field value throughout the report.

Comment: It looks like zero. I wound up creating a formula to reset the shared variable to 0 and added a second group header. Then put the reset formula in the first header and the subreport in the second header. That appears to have fixed it.

Comment: But now I have a second report that works similar except there is only group and only one output for each group  but I'm encountering the same problems and tried the same solution but that's not working. The subreport located in group 1 header b gives incorrect totals.

Comment: I wound creating another Group 2 footer and put the subreport in the first footer and all my info in the second footer. Then I put the reset variable in the header and that fixed everything.